# Larger index size after Elasticsearch reindex

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

After performing a reindex on a 75GB index, the new one went to 79GB.

Both indexes have the same doc count (54,123,676) and both have the exact same mapping. The original index has 6*2 shards and the new one has 3*2 shards.

The original index also has 75,857 deleted documents which were not moved across, so we are pretty stumped as to how it could even be smaller than the new one at all, let alone by a whole 4GB.

**Original Index**

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 12,
        "successful": 12,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "_all": {
        "primaries": {
            "docs": {
                "count": 54123676,
                "deleted": 75857
            },
            "store": {
                "size_in_bytes": 75357819717,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            },
            ...
            "segments": {
                "count": 6,
                "memory_in_bytes": 173650124,
                "terms_memory_in_bytes": 152493380,
                "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 17914688,
                "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "norms_memory_in_bytes": 79424,
                "points_memory_in_bytes": 2728328,
                "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 434304,
                "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                "file_sizes": {}
            }
            ...
```

**New Index**

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "total": 6,
        "successful": 6,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "_all": {
        "primaries": {
            "docs": {
                "count": 54123676,
                "deleted": 0
            },
            "store": {
                "size_in_bytes": 79484557149,
                "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
            },
            ...
            "segments": {
                "count": 3,
                "memory_in_bytes": 166728713,
                "terms_memory_in_bytes": 145815659,
                "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 17870464,
                "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "norms_memory_in_bytes": 37696,
                "points_memory_in_bytes": 2683802,
                "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 321092,
                "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0,
                "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp": -1,
                "file_sizes": {}
            }
            ...
```

Any clues?

Comment: Have you wait a little? Es merge data and could free some space in background. But i have no idea for a 75Go index how many time es need to complete it...

Comment: Yeah it's been almost a week now, with no changes

Answer (score 1):

You should use segment merge feature. Since segments are immutable ES always creates new ones and slowly it merges itself. But this request will help you solve your problem.It merges all segments and save memory. But when you send this request, beware of that this request is little heavy. So choose off-peak hours to execute.

`POST /_forcemerge?only_expunge_deletes=true`

Comment: I had run `POST /_forcemerge?max_num_segments=1`, but after processing it the result was still the same size. I don't think `only_expunge_deletes` will help much, as there are 0 deleted documents

Comment: It is not about deleted documents. After reindex operation there are lots of memory segments to be merged. You only make this process faster. After executing this request you should wait 5-10 mins.

Comment: I re-ran the `_forecemerge`, this time with the `only_expunge_deletes=true`, but the size is still 79484557149 bytes, even after 30mins :( I've updated my question to add the `segments` nodes which might hopefully have some more info

Comment: Are both indexes in same cluster?

Comment: Yup, both in the same cluster